# Why would an image clustered to two segments using k-means (from Scipy) show more than two different pixel values?

Tags: python, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation

I am using the KMeans clustering available with Scikit Learn library of python to segment a color image. Since I needed only the green channel, I set the other two channels to zero.
From the elbow plot, I have found that two clusters are optimal for the image.
Now, when I do the clustering, I have more than two pixel values present in the segmented image. How is this possible? I thought that segmentation like KMeans really keeps only two clusters at the end.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code that you used, it is not clear how exactly you obtained the output image. See [mre].

Comment: `image = cv2.imread('NJ_G_03_09_100X_green_channel_6p5.png')`
`image2 = image.reshape((-1,3))`
`image2 = np.float32(image2)`
`criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1.0)`
`k = 2`
`number_of_runs = 10`
`ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(image2, k, None, criteria, number_of_runs, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)`
`center = np.uint8(center)`
`res = center[label.flatten()]`
`res2 = res.reshape((image.shape))`
`print(center)`
`cv2.imwrite('NJ_G_03_09_100X_green_channel_6p5_segmented2iter100.jpg', res2)`

Comment: Sorry, I can’t read that. Please [edit] your question with amendments, comments are not for important information. Also, please include the import statements so we can see what modules you use.

Comment: One thing I do notice is that you use `cv2.kmeans`, which is not from Scikit Learn but from OpenCV. All these details are highly important, so please make sure your description actually matches what you did.

Comment: I also see you write your output as a JPEG. This might create additional colors due to compression artifacts. Is that what is happening? Do you still see more than two colors if you save as PNG?

Comment: PNG is looking fine, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, *, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, algorithm='auto')
```

According to Scikit Learn's documentation [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html?highlight=k%20means#sklearn.cluster.KMeans), you should be the one to decide how many clusters your K-Means model output.

If you're not sure about the number of clusters, maybe you can try Hierarchical clustering [2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering).

Comment: I have chosen the number of clusters to be 2 and then performed the segmentation. My question is about the final image having pixel values of more than two kind.

Comment: I have chosen the number of clusters to be 2 and then performed the segmentation. My question is about the final image having pixel values of more than two kind. For example, lets say I had a green image with regions having pixel value = 180 +- 10 and another region with 250 +- 10. So, I was expecting the final image to have say regions of 180 alone and 250 alone. NO numbers other than 180 or 250. But this is not how the output looks like, it again contained, lets say, 182, 185, 179, 256, 248...Why does this happen? I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, have you try increasing the "max_iter" parameter? Cause K-Means need enough iteration to minimize the inertia.

Comment: Also this may help you have a better understanding of what K-means does [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#:~:text=Given%20enough%20time,in%20the%20reference.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried improving the number of iterations to 100, but doesn't solve the problem.